# Code First Migration and creating a mdf in a class library

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Solution with three projects. One are the models, another is the repository and context configuration and the last one is a Web application.
The things is that when i configure the Entity Framework in the Repository Project and add the migrations, and i try to execute update-migration nuget console this throw me and error.
I need the database in a mdf file so the app.config look this way:

The error when i try to update-migration is:

> The physical file name "/ExampleDB.mdf" may be incorrect

By the error i understand that `|DataDirectory|` is not working and i can't set it with
 `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());` because this project is a class library.

Thanks a lot